# How do I create a limit of logins on my login screen?

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to design an atm machine in C# and I am quite new to this.
I would like my login screen to Return back to my welcome screen after 3 failed attempt's at trying to login but I do not know where to start and how to implement my code into my program to do this.

My current code is as follows for my login screen:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace bankkk
{
    public partial class FrmLogin : Form
    {
        public FrmLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();

        string dbProvider;
        string dbSource;

        OleDbDataAdapter da;

        public static DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

        string sql;
        string pin;
        int rownum = 0;
        bool valid = false;

        private void FrmLogin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;";
            dbSource = "Data Source = 'd:\\bank11.accdb'";
            con.ConnectionString = dbProvider + dbSource;
            ds1 = new DataSet();
            con.Open();
            sql = " SELECT tblCustomers.* FROM tblCustomers";
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
            rownum = da.Fill(ds1, "tblCustomers");

            con.Close();
        }

        private void btnexit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            System.Environment.Exit(0);
            this.Close();

        }


        //METHOD VALIDATE

        private bool validate()
        {
            ds1 = new DataSet();
            con.Open();

            sql = "SELECT tblCustomers.* FROM tblCustomers WHERE ((tblCustomers.AccountNo) = '" + txtAccount.Text + "')";
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
            rownum = da.Fill(ds1, "tblCustomers");
            con.Close();

            if (rownum != 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not a valid Account");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                pin = ds1.Tables["tblCustomers"].Rows[0][4].ToString();
                if (pin == txtPin.Text)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("INVALID PIN");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            valid = validate();
            if (valid == true)
            {
                if (txtAccount.Text == "11111111" && txtPin.Text == "9999")
                {
                    Frmmanager Manager = new Frmmanager();
                    this.Close();
                    Manager.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    frmaccount account = new frmaccount();
                    this.Close();
                    account.Show();

                    {
                        txtAccount.Clear();
                        txtPin.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnlogin_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            valid = validate();
            if (valid == true)
            {
                if (txtAccount.Text == "11111111" && txtPin.Text == "9999")
                {
                    Frmmanager Manager = new Frmmanager();
                    this.Close();
                    Manager.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    frmaccount account = new frmaccount();
                    this.Close();
                    account.Show();

                    {
                        txtAccount.Clear();
                        txtPin.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O.o you don't know where to start after doing SQL statements?. Have you considered making a simple login application from scratch, without the database stuff?

Comment: You just need to store the number of failed logins in a variable, and check against that.

Comment: Use variable to store count of failed login attempts, increment this value on each login failure, check that variable value on button click

Comment: by the way, the `valid` variable is already a `Boolean`, so you don't need to do `if (valid == true)`. Instead, just do `if (valid)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying *Return back to my welcome screen*, so I'll suppose that you are showing the `FrmLogin` using `.ShowDialog()` instead of `.Show()`. That way, you just need to close your old form.

If you are just doing `.Show()`, you can do something like this:

```
public partial class FrmWelcome {

    //in some part of your code...
    var frmLogin = new FrmLogin();

    //when the login form is closed, show this one.
    //Depending on your application, you might want to add some boolean variable
    //to the Login Form that will be true if the user authentication failed, and 
    //show this form again only if it is true.
    frmLogin.Closed += (s, e) => this.Show();

    this.Hide();
    frmLogin.Show();
}
```

**Try the below code.** The idea is to have a `failedAttempts` variable, which will be incremented everytime your validation code fails. When it is equals to 3, you just close the form (see above).

```
namespace bankkk
{
    public partial class FrmLogin : Form
    {
        public FrmLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        ...

        int failedAttempts = 0;

        private void btnlogin_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            valid = validate();
            if (!valid) {
                //Increment the number of failed attempts
                failedAttempts += 1;

                //If equal to 3
                if (failedAttempts == 3) {
                    //Just close this window
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //the same code you were using...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DavidHughes I edited my answer to add some explanations in addition to the code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable to your program and increment it to limit the number of attempts to login at all. To limit the number of attempts for an account add a table to store login information, including invalid attempts, to your database. Link that table to your Customer table. When an invalid attempt is made to login to a valid customer account increment the number of invalid attempts and write it back to the login table. On a successful login you can set the number of invalid attempts to 0.